# Throws uncaught exception while adding subview in a table row

Tags: iphone, addsubview

```
[checkButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectorClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:checkButton1];
[checkButton1 release];
```

Line 2 throws uncaught exception. Do you have any idea? If i comment line 2 it works fine but also doesn't add view into subview.

Thanks,

Amit Singh

Comment: When asking a question on SO, it is better to indicate (at least in the tags) the language and more information (platform, framework, etc.). It allows to filter (and attract) people able to answer it.

Comment: Further to @PhiLho's comment, including the exception output would also be rather useful

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialize the button object?